# Ubuntu kill java program started by bash

Tags: java, shell, ubuntu, services, kill

I've got a problem with killing my Java Program on Ubuntu. I created the following init script:

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          control ...
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: ...
# Description:       ...
### END INIT INFO

DAEMON_PATH="/mnt/Data/wstlm"
DAEMON=startWstlm
DAEMONOPTS=""

NAME=wstlm
DESC="My daemon description"
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME

case "$1" in
start)
        printf "%-50s" "Starting $NAME..."
        cd $DAEMON_PATH
        PID=`./$DAEMON $DAEMONOPTS > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!`
        echo "Saving PID" $PID " to " $PIDFILE
        if [ -z $PID ]; then
            printf "%s\n" "Fail"
        else
            echo $PID > $PIDFILE
            printf "%s\n" "Ok"
        fi
;;
status)
        printf "%-50s" "Checking $NAME..."
        if [ -f $PIDFILE ]; then
            PID=`cat $PIDFILE`
            if [ -z "`ps axf | grep ${PID} | grep -v grep`" ]; then
                printf "%s\n" "Process dead but pidfile exists"
            else
                echo "Running"
            fi
        else
            printf "%s\n" "Service not running"
        fi
;;
stop)
        printf "%-50s" "Stopping $NAME"
            PID=`cat $PIDFILE`
            cd $DAEMON_PATH
        if [ -f $PIDFILE ]; then
            kill -9 $PID
            printf "%s\n" "Ok"
            rm -f $PIDFILE
        else
            printf "%s\n" "pidfile not found"
        fi
;;

restart)
    $0 stop
    $0 start
;;

*)
        echo "Usage: $0 {status|start|stop|restart}"
        exit 1
esac
```

This init script changes the directory to my program and the content of the executed startWstlm is:

> #!/bin/sh
>       echo `date +"%Y/%m/%d %T"` - start WSTLm 1>>/mnt/Data/wstlm/wstlm.log
>       java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=jssecacerts -jar /mnt/Data/wstlm/myProgram.jar

I added the init script to the init.d. If i call

> sudo service myProgram start

The program starts properly. But if I use

> sudo service myProgram stop

The Program doesn't shut down. Only the bash command which started my java program is killed.

Before executing stop:

> 1 root /bin/sh ./startWstlm
>       2 root java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=jssecacerts -jar /mnt/Data/wstlm/myProgram.jar
>       3 root java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=jssecacerts -jar /mnt/Data/wstlm/myProgram.jar
>       4 root java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=jssecacerts -jar /mnt/Data/wstlm/myProgram.jar

After executing stop:

> (note this bash was killed)
>       2 root java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=jssecacerts -jar /mnt/Data/wstlm/myProgram.jar
>       3 root java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=jssecacerts -jar /mnt/Data/wstlm/myProgram.jar
>       4 root java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=jssecacerts -jar /mnt/Data/wstlm/myProgram.jar

(By the way: why there are multiple processes of this jar?)

So the problem is that I cant stop my program. What is kind of .. annoying. Has anyone an idea?

Comment: I'm surprised this was migrated; it seems like a fairly standard problem in shell programming.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use `kill -9`; a simple `kill` should be sufficient. Second, see [this page](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SignalTrap) for a good explanation of how to kill child processes when the parent is told to exit. In this case, `startWstim` needs to take care of killing the Java program before it exits.

Finally, it might be simpler to dispense with `startWstim`, and instead execute the commands it contains directly in your init script:

```
start)
    printf "%-50s" "Starting $NAME..."
    cd $DAEMON_PATH
    echo "$(date +"%Y/%m/%d %T") - start WSTLm" >> /mnt/Data/wstlm/wstlm.log
    java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=jssecacerts -jar /mnt/Data/wstlm/myProgram.jar &
    PID=$!
```

Note that you don't need a subshell to get the process ID of the Java program, and you need to  capture the output of the `date` command in order to print it to the log file.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. I followed your approach to use kill and implement the start commands in the init script only.